# Parsing DateTime of unspecified language

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I'm currently trying to parse a timestamp that could be in **any** language, and am having difficulty getting TryParseExact to work. 
There's unfortunately no way to check what the language is anywhere else in my data so there's no way to parse this easily (that I know of). I've been googling around this topic for a while and can't seem to find anyone with a similar problem or usable solution.

Sample date: `Lunes, 16 de febrero de 2015 a las 18:49 UTC-05`

Format I've got so far, from looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.90).aspx: `dddd, d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy 'a las' HH:mm 'UTC'zz` *

My test code: <s>http://ideone.com/o1yknS</s> http://ideone.com/bZOD4H

Why does this not parse correctly? And how can I find an elegant solution to this?

*My problem here is that I don't know how to get rid of the 'a las' and 'de' in the string. These might not always be the same length or even in the same position so I can't just use substrings. I'm just using this string to test on for now though.

Comment: That's not invariant culture.  You could just loop through a set of cultures and pass them to `DateTime.TryParse` until one works.  On another note, why are you getting date strings in different cultures?  That's you're real problem.

Comment: I'm trying to parse facebook data dumps so I really don't have any control over the languages I get this data in. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a try.

Comment: this will list the cultures https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures(v=vs.110).aspx  you probably want to try in an order of most likely.  And if it is all digits you won't know mm/dd/yy from dd/mm/yy - so dates compliant with both are a quess.

Comment: Please post the code here, not on some external website. See the Help Center's topic on [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dateTimeFormat` works fine, however you are doing `ToLower()`, so it's not finding `UTC`.

So either remove the `ToLower()` or change your `dateTimeFormat` string to use `utc` and not `UTC`.

I've forked your Ideone snippet and just removed `ToLower()` on the datetime string and `d1` gets parsed perfectly fine: http://ideone.com/Wstxaz

Copied the code here, just in case the link goes down:

```
// Removed `ToLower()` at the end
string date = "Lunes, 16 de febrero de 2015 a las 18:49 UTC-05";
string dateTimeFormat = "dddd, d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy 'a las' HH:mm UTCzz";
DateTime d1;
DateTime.TryParseExact(date, 
                       dateTimeFormat, 
                       CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES"),
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out d1);
```

Now for your problem: if you don't know the format(s) you'll receive the string in, it's impossible to parse it. You need a format (or a list of formats) to be able to parse a datetime in a string. There are too much possibly ambiguous figures in a date & time string to just be able to figure it out unequivocally.

Comment: Thank you! Good spot on the ToLower thing, can't believe that mistake was so simple! I've ended up creating a file with format/locale pairs, so I'll loop through and try to find out the language from that.

Comment: @goshcharlotte that's reasonable, as long as you make sure all possible formats are unambiguous (`mm/dd/yy` would be ambiguous to `dd/mm/yy` , for example, if there are no other differences)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for your whole problem, but you can parse your example string with the given format:

```
string dateTimeFormat = @"dddd, d \de MMMM \de yyyy a la\s HH:mm UTCzz";
DateTime d1;
DateTime.TryParseExact(date, dateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES"), DateTimeStyles.None, out d1);
```

Note the escaped "d" and "s" characters, the HH for 24-hour time format, and the zz without the - in front. Also note that the spanish culture info is required in order to parse the spanish day and month names.